# Getting an UnsatisfiableError when installing a package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install the pairtools (https://github.com/mirnylab/pairtools) package on Mac terminal using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda pairtools
```

When I run this I am getting the following error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - pip -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
```

Is this a version problem? The current version of python I have is 3.7.3.
How do I correct this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I updated the packages before running the above command by:
conda update anaconda and conda update --all

Comment: What happens if you try installing the package into a new environment i.e. `conda create -n newenvname ...` instead of `conda install ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I did try that way and it worked: `conda create -n newenv python=3.7.2; conda activate newenv; conda install -y -c conda-forge -c bioconda pairtools; conda deactivate newenv`.

Comment: Cool, I'll write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this sort of dependency conflict when using `conda`, create a new environment with just your chosen packages in it:

```
conda create -n newenvname -c channelname package1 package2
```

creates an environment called `newenvname` containing `package1`, `package2` and their dependencies, and searches channel `channelname` as well as the default channels (leave out `-c channelname` to use only the defaults). For more help type `conda create --help`. If you want to use the Spyder IDE in this env, don't forget to include the `spyder-kernels` package.

I would actually advise always leaving the base conda environment untouched and creating one or more working environments which you can `install` into or `upgrade` to your heart's content, safe in the knowledge that in the worst case you can simply delete that env and recreate it, without messing up your Anaconda installation.